# How can I delete unnecessary information in a table with python 2.7?

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I have  a web-scraping table :

```html
<TABLE BORDER="0" ID="pm" CLASS="tab6col">
<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><B>2015. év</B></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><B>2014. év</B></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><B>2013. év</B></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><B>2012. év</B></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><B>2011. év</B></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword"><B>Beszámolási időszak</B></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><span class="pm_idoszak">2015.01.01. - 2015.12.31.</span></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><span class="pm_idoszak">2014.01.01. - 2014.12.31.</span></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><span class="pm_idoszak">2013.12.30. - 2013.12.31.</span></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><span class="pm_idoszak">Nincs adat.</span></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><span class="pm_idoszak">Nincs adat.</span></TD></TR><TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right">eFt</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right">eFt</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right">eFt</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right">eFt</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right">eFt</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Értékesítés nettó árbevétele</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Bevételek</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">2 873 821</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">3 162 742</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">9 194</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Üzemi eredmény</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">81 937</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-181 850</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 755</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Adózás előtti eredmény</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-192 778</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-169 476</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 755</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Mérleg szerinti eredmény</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-124 099</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 421</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Adózott eredmény</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-192 778</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-169 476</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 579</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Eszközök összesen</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">37 820 881</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">40 695 842</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">36 992 091</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Befektetett eszközök</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">18 668 826</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">18 525 063</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">16 925 711</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Forgóeszközök</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">19 008 587</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">21 877 275</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">19 792 420</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Pénzeszközök</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">947 015</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 056 101</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 307 515</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Aktív időbeli elhatárolások</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">143 468</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">293 504</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">273 960</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Saját tőke</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">2 141 319</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">2 184 079</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">2 353 554</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Céltartalékok</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">29 656</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">148 652</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">18 960</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Kötelezettségek</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">35 541 531</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">38 059 399</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">34 233 518</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Rövid lejáratú kötelezettségek</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">30 519 491</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">30 426 014</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">26 394 088</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Hosszú lejáratú kötelezettségek</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">5 022 040</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">7 633 385</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">7 839 430</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Passzív időbeli elhatárolások</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">108 375</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">303 712</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">386 059</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword" colspan="6"><B>Pénzügyi mutatók</B></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Eladósodottság foka <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Eladósodottság foka&lt;/span&gt; (Kötelezettségek/Eszközök összesen)&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;Megmutatja, hogy az eszköz állomány milyen mértékben van megterhelve kötelezettségvállalással. Minél kisebb a mutató értéke, annál jobb a cég megítélése.&lt;/i&gt;');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Eladósodottság mértéke - Bonitás <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Eladósodottság mértéke - Bonitás&lt;/span&gt; (Kötelezettségek/Saját tőke)&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;Azt mutatja, hogy a saját források a kötelezettségek hány százalékát fedezik. Pozitív a cég megítélése, ha a mutató értéke tartósan (jóval) 1 alatt van.&lt;/i&gt;');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Árbevétel arányos eredmény % <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Árbevétel arányos eredmény %&lt;/span&gt; (Adózott eredmény/ Nettó árbevétel)&times;100&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;A mutató az árbevétel hatékonyságát fejezi ki úgy, hogy az árbevétel nyereségtartalmát százalékban szemlélteti. A cég megítélése annál pozitívabb, minél magasabb a százalék.&lt;/i&gt;');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Likviditási gyorsráta <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Likviditási gyorsráta&lt;/span&gt; ((Forgóeszközök-Készletek)/Rövid lej.kötelezettségek)&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;Azt fejezi ki, hogy az egy év alatt pénzzé tehető készletek nélküli forgóeszközök milyen arányban képesek az egy éven belül esedékes kötelezettségek fedezésére, azaz milyen a cég rövid távú fizetőképessége.&lt;br&gt;A cég megítélése akkor pozitív, ha ez az arány egyre növekvő, ami az azonnali fizetőképesség javulását jelzi.&lt;/i&gt;');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Saját tőke aránya <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Saját tőke aránya &lt;/span&gt; (Saját tőke / Források)');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,06</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,05</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,06</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Eszközarányos nyereség <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Eszközarányos nyereség &lt;/span&gt; (Adózott eredmény / Eszközök)');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-0,01</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,00</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,00</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Bevételarányos eredmény <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Bevételarányos eredmény &lt;/span&gt; (Adózott eredmény / Bevételek)');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-0,07</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-0,05</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,17</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Saját tőke arányos nyereség <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Saját tőke arányos nyereség &lt;/span&gt; (Adózott eredmény / Saját tőke)');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-0,09</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-0,08</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,00</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword" colspan="6"><B>Létszám:</B> &nbsp; 136 fő</TD>
</TR></TABLE>
```

For example this values :

```html
TD class="contentword">Saját tőke aránya <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Saját tőke aránya &lt;/span&gt; (Saját tőke / Források)');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><
```

I need only "Saját tőke aránya" and that's all, but with this 'span style' create a character "i" in the end these dataes which are unnecessary for me.
How can I delete these values?

Here my code:

```js
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb
 
filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
 
f = open('opten2.txt', 'r')
x = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(x, 'lxml')
 
tab6col = soup.find('table', { "class" : "tab6col" })
datatable=[]
for record in tab6col.find_all('tr'):
    temp_data = []
    for data in record.find_all('td'):
        temp_data.append(data.text.encode('latin-1'))
    datatable.append(temp_data)
  
output.writerows(datatable)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can kick span tag out of code by using `extract()`:

```
html='''<TABLE BORDER="0" ID="pm" CLASS="tab6col">
<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><B>2015. év</B></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><B>2014. év</B></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><B>2013. év</B></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><B>2012. év</B></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><B>2011. év</B></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword"><B>Beszámolási időszak</B></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><span class="pm_idoszak">2015.01.01. - 2015.12.31.</span></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><span class="pm_idoszak">2014.01.01. - 2014.12.31.</span></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><span class="pm_idoszak">2013.12.30. - 2013.12.31.</span></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><span class="pm_idoszak">Nincs adat.</span></TD><TD class="contentword" align="right"><span class="pm_idoszak">Nincs adat.</span></TD></TR><TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right">eFt</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right">eFt</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right">eFt</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right">eFt</TD><TD class="contentword" align="right">eFt</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Értékesítés nettó árbevétele</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Bevételek</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">2 873 821</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">3 162 742</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">9 194</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Üzemi eredmény</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">81 937</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-181 850</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 755</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Adózás előtti eredmény</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-192 778</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-169 476</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 755</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Mérleg szerinti eredmény</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-124 099</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 421</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Adózott eredmény</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-192 778</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-169 476</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 579</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Eszközök összesen</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">37 820 881</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">40 695 842</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">36 992 091</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Befektetett eszközök</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">18 668 826</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">18 525 063</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">16 925 711</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Forgóeszközök</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">19 008 587</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">21 877 275</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">19 792 420</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Pénzeszközök</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">947 015</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 056 101</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">1 307 515</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Aktív időbeli elhatárolások</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">143 468</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">293 504</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">273 960</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Saját tőke</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">2 141 319</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">2 184 079</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">2 353 554</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Céltartalékok</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">29 656</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">148 652</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">18 960</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Kötelezettségek</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">35 541 531</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">38 059 399</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">34 233 518</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Rövid lejáratú kötelezettségek</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">30 519 491</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">30 426 014</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">26 394 088</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Hosszú lejáratú kötelezettségek</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">5 022 040</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">7 633 385</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">7 839 430</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Passzív időbeli elhatárolások</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">108 375</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">303 712</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">386 059</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword" colspan="6"><B>Pénzügyi mutatók</B></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Eladósodottság foka <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Eladósodottság foka&lt;/span&gt; (Kötelezettségek/Eszközök összesen)&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;Megmutatja, hogy az eszköz állomány milyen mértékben van megterhelve kötelezettségvállalással. Minél kisebb a mutató értéke, annál jobb a cég megítélése.&lt;/i&gt;');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Eladósodottság mértéke - Bonitás <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Eladósodottság mértéke - Bonitás&lt;/span&gt; (Kötelezettségek/Saját tőke)&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;Azt mutatja, hogy a saját források a kötelezettségek hány százalékát fedezik. Pozitív a cég megítélése, ha a mutató értéke tartósan (jóval) 1 alatt van.&lt;/i&gt;');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Árbevétel arányos eredmény % <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Árbevétel arányos eredmény %&lt;/span&gt; (Adózott eredmény/ Nettó árbevétel)&times;100&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;A mutató az árbevétel hatékonyságát fejezi ki úgy, hogy az árbevétel nyereségtartalmát százalékban szemlélteti. A cég megítélése annál pozitívabb, minél magasabb a százalék.&lt;/i&gt;');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Likviditási gyorsráta <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Likviditási gyorsráta&lt;/span&gt; ((Forgóeszközök-Készletek)/Rövid lej.kötelezettségek)&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;Azt fejezi ki, hogy az egy év alatt pénzzé tehető készletek nélküli forgóeszközök milyen arányban képesek az egy éven belül esedékes kötelezettségek fedezésére, azaz milyen a cég rövid távú fizetőképessége.&lt;br&gt;A cég megítélése akkor pozitív, ha ez az arány egyre növekvő, ami az azonnali fizetőképesség javulását jelzi.&lt;/i&gt;');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">Nincs adat.</TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Saját tőke aránya <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Saját tőke aránya &lt;/span&gt; (Saját tőke / Források)');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,06</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,05</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,06</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Eszközarányos nyereség <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Eszközarányos nyereség &lt;/span&gt; (Adózott eredmény / Eszközök)');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-0,01</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,00</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,00</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Bevételarányos eredmény <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Bevételarányos eredmény &lt;/span&gt; (Adózott eredmény / Bevételek)');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-0,07</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-0,05</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,17</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword">Saját tőke arányos nyereség <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Saját tőke arányos nyereség &lt;/span&gt; (Adózott eredmény / Saját tőke)');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-0,09</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">-0,08</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right">0,00</TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD><TD class="numberc" align="right"></TD></TR><TR><TD class="contentword" colspan="6"><B>Létszám:</B> &nbsp; 136 fő</TD>
</TR></TABLE>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

tab6col = soup.find('table', { "class" : "tab6col" })
datatable=[]
for record in tab6col.find_all('tr'):
    temp_data = []
    for data in record.find_all('td'):
        if data.span:
            data.span.extract()
        temp_data.append(data.text)
    datatable.append(temp_data)
```

Comment: It is work, but unfortunately with this method i lose these dataes too but i need them :

"<span class="pm_idoszak">2015.01.01. - 2015.12.31.</span></TD>"

Comment: initially you said that you need only first text,
please give output example

Comment: I wrote an example which is cause a sign "i".
 "TD class="contentword">Saját tőke aránya <span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; font-family: InformationLogo, Webdings;" onmouseover="show_hint(this, '&lt;span style=&quot;color: red; font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;Saját tőke aránya &lt;/span&gt; (Saját tőke / Források)');" onmouseout="remove_hint();">&#105;</span></TD>"